# How to input period as decimal point?

Tags: java

I need to make a program that find the minimum difference of an array of float by sorting it first. The problem is the Scanner wont take period (.) as a decimal point (for example if i input 2.251 it will read it as 2251.0).
Here is a part of the code

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Selisih {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        float[] arr = new float[m];
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
            arr[i] = sc.nextFloat();
        }
        quickSort(arr, 0, m - 1);
        System.out.printf("%.3f", minDiff(arr));
    }
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could reduce the example a bit so we can focus on the `Scanner` problem you're having? This may also help you debug the issue.

Comment: Maybe this depends on your locale, have you tried it with a comma instead of a dot? Oh, I see, that's not the problem, you are reading an `int` from `System.in` by doing `int m = sc.nextInt();`. Change it to `int m = sc.nextFloat();`, maybe that helps.

Comment: @deHaar just tried, it works with comma

Comment: @deHaar the m is only used as an index for the array

Comment: @GianMartin ok, I see... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What character is used to separate groups within numbers and integral vs. decimal parts is controlled by the [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) in use. If you do:

```
System.out.println(String.format("Group: %s Decimal: %s", 
    DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).getGroupingSeparator(),
    DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).getDecimalSeparator()));
```

You will get which is which for your default locale.

To use the dot as a decimal separator in a locale-consistent way, set the `Scanner`'s locale to the correct one, presumably one that uses the dot as the decimal separator, as opposed to a grouping separator. An example is `Locale.US`:

```
try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    sc.useLocale(Locale.US);
    int m = sc.nextInt();
    float[] arr = new float[m];
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        arr[i] = sc.nextFloat();
    }
}
```

Then you should get:

```
2.251 -> 2.251
2,251 -> 2251.0
```