# Error from scan nextDouble, how do I fix the problem?

Tags: java, double, point

There is an error when I enter the double next value with a point like (1.5) I don't know why?

Even when I put (1,5) with the comma, the same result is wrong.

Can anyone help me fix it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ex1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    double inch;

    System.out.println("write the distance in inch:");
    inch = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("the result is " + inch * 2.54 + " cm");
}
}
```

the output:

```
write the distance in inch:
1.5
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:943)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1598)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2569)
at ex1.main(ex1.java:10)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What happens if you enter a number with no decimal point?  `10`, for example?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Without the decimal point, the program works

Comment: Add this to your code: `System.out.println ( "Decimal Separator is '" + (new DecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()) +"'");`, and let us know the result.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer The code is not working because ' DecimalFormatSymbols ' It appears that there is an error. cannot find the symbol class DecimalFormatSymbol

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. Also add `import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;`

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer The code is working now, but it shows the same output that I wrote in the question. The problem is not solved

Comment: But, what does the "Decimal  Separator" line show?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer  Decimal Separator is '٫'

Comment: I made a mistake. Decimal Separator is '٫'

Comment: Strange.  That's saying it should work if you use a comma as the decimal point. If you want to use a period, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57924766/how-to-input-period-as-decimal-point

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Thank you, the program works now when I copy the decimal point that appeared in ' Decimal Separator is '٫' ' and paste it in the distance in inch the output:
Decimal Separator is '٫'
write the distance in inch:
1٫5
the result is 3.81 cm

Comment: It looks like a comma (,) to me. But, if I copy and paste to this line `System.out.println ((',' == '٫') ? "same" : "different");`, I get "different"  (The comma is to the left of `==` and the other character on the right.)

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer I also get "different"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your computer is set to use the [Arabic Decimal Separator](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=066B). If you use that instead of a period (.) or comma (,), your program should work.

If you want users to be able to use a period as a decimal separator, you can add `scan.useLocale(Locale.US);` just after opening the `Scanner`

```
 import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
 import java.util.Locale;                      
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class ex1 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      scan.useLocale(Locale.US);              // **** new line ****
   
      double inch;

      System.out.print("write the distance in inch: ");
      inch = scan.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("the result is " + inch * 2.54 + " cm");
   }
}
```

See [How to input period as decimal point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57924766/how-to-input-period-as-decimal-point)

You could stick with the Arabic Decimal Separator. If you want to change it, you don't have to use `Locale.US`. You could use a different locale that uses a period. Or, a locale that uses a comma. Or, some other character.

Adding that line will affect only that `Scanner` Object. You can change it for one program by using command line options, or by adding `Locale.setDefault(new Locale(~~~~));` (You have to substitute valid language, language and country, or language, country, and variant for ~~~~.  You can change it for your Java installation. You can change it system wide. See [How do I set the default locale in the JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-in-the-jvm) .